# Opening local html file with parameters after #

Tags: c#, url

I am trying to open a local html file. I am using the following code:

```
ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo(encoded)
{
  UseShellExecute = true,
  Verb = "open"
};

Process.Start(ps);
```

I am trying to open the same file both remotely and locally. When opening the file remotely, everything works fine. WHen trying to open the file locally, the parameter is being removed and the URL opens on the start page.

Remote URL:
[https://myserver.com/help/release/1.0/Index.htm#cshid=OPTIONS"](https://myserver.com/help/release/1.0/Index.htm#cshid=OPTIONS%22)

Local URL:
file://D:/App/release/1.0/Component/Help/Index.htm#cshid=OPTIONS"

I tried tinkering with the 'ProcessStartInfo' but I can not get this to work with local files. Is there any way to do this with a simple call? As a workaround I got the default browser from the registry and started it manually. But I would like to have a simple call that works for every browser.

Comment: Possible side note: It should be `file:///D...`. you're missing one forward slash.

Comment: When you say "the url opens on the start page", do you mean the webbrowser start page, or the "index.htm without cshid" page? If the former, then sticky bit's comment above is likely to be *the answer*. Seems unlikely to be the latter, but if it is, there might be something else involved... On another side note, which browser do you use? Using MS Edge Chromium, it seems to automatically replace `file://D` with `file:///D`, therefore no problem with this

Comment: ... (continued) using IE11 however, having `file://D` will result in "*Windows can't find [path]*"

Comment: By "opens the start page" I mean that the basic url is opened (without parameter) and not the browser start page.